# Передача данных с одной формы на другую

Tags: c#, list

Есть следующий код

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    List<int> Y = new List<int>();
    List<int> X = new List<int>();
    bool flagok = true;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public bool Ff
    {
        get
        {
            return flagok;
        }
    }


    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        int y = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(x, y);
        X.Add(x);
        Y.Add(y);

    }
    public List<int> SendX
    {
        get
        {
            return X;
        }
    }

    public List<int> SendY
    {
        get
        {
            return Y;
        }
    }
```

Списки Х и Y при передаче с одной формы на другую остаются пустыми. Не могу понять,где ошибка
Передача на другой форме. По моей задумке,должна происходить при нажатии кнопки:

```
 private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(picture);
        SolidBrush t = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        x = hands.SendX;
        y = hands.SendY;
        for (int i = 0; i < x.Count; i++)
        {

            g.FillEllipse(t, x[i] - 7, y[i] - 7, 10, 10);

        }
        pictureBox1.Image = picture;
```

Comment: где в вашем коде передача?

Comment: Передача в другой форме и выглядит так:x = hands.SendX;
                                                                       y = hands.SendY; hands-название формы

Comment: Добавьте полный кусок кода передачи в вопрос. То, что вы в комментарий написали, мне не говорит ни о чем.